# Count distinct groups in distributed grouping in Solr

Tags: solr, grouping, distribute, fieldcollapsing

Is there any way to get the number of distinct groups in a distributed grouping in solr?

The ngroups param returns the summatory of all groups. If a group exists in more than one shard I will have repeated this groups in the ngroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [SOLR-3316](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3316) and [SOLR-3436](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3436).
May be an existing issue which is fixed.

Comment: I send a email to Martijn van Groningen (the author of patch for issue SOLR-3316) and he confirmed me that the result of ngroup is in fact the sum of all groups and not the distinct groups. Unfortunately, there isn't any funcionality that do that I want.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions to this now:

http://yonik.com/solr-count-distinct/

You can use the stats component with pivot faceting, use group with group.facet or use the new analytics API that shipped in 5.2 (5.1. didn't seem to work when I tried it).